# remote login with php curl to coinbase

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I am trying to create a script to login remotely to coinbase.com, but i get javascript is not enabled on submit if user/pass combination is valid. Else i get the correct response that user or pass is invalid.
Is there anyway to bypass the javascript error?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the code :

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
error_reporting(0);
    $user=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['password'];

$random=rand(1, 100000);
$cookie=$random . ".txt";
$agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0";

function doRequest($method, $url, $referer, $agent, $cookie, $vars) {
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if($referer != "") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    }
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    if ($method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }

    if (substr($url, 0, 5) == "https") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    }
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($data) {
        return $data;
    } else {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
}

function get($url, $referer, $agent, $cookie) {
    return doRequest('GET', $url, $referer, $agent, $cookie, 'NULL');
}

function post($url, $referer, $agent, $cookie, $vars) {
    return doRequest('POST', $url, $referer, $agent, $cookie, $vars);
}
function between1($src,$start,$end){
    $txt=explode($start,$src);
    $txt2=explode($end,$txt[1]);
    return trim($txt2[0]);
}
$url = "https://www.coinbase.com/signin";
$referer = "";
$result=get($url,'',$agent,$cookie);
$token=between1($result, 'name="authenticity_token" value="', '"');
$utf=between1($result, 'name="utf8" type="hidden" value="', '"');
$token=urlencode($token);
$utf=urlencode($utf);
$url="https://ws.coinbase.com/app/d7be708e7945ebab11a34c530cb4dc?protocol=7&client=js&version=2.2.3&flash=false";
$result=get($url,'',$agent,$cookie);
$url="https://www.coinbase.com/sessions";
$referer="https://www.coinbase.com/signin";
$vars="utf8=".$utf."&authenticity_token=".$token."&email=".urlencode($user)."&password=".urlencode($pass)."&commit=Sign+In: undefined";
$result=post($url,$referer,$agent,$cookie,$vars);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Coinbase has [an API](https://developers.coinbase.com/) so that you don't have to do stuff like this...

Comment: I need to add more sessions ( different users ) at once.. The api and oauth fails when calling.

Comment: _"oauth fails when calling"_ **That's** the issue you probably should be posting about. :)